# Integrating $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$ using log of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I was trying to solve the above using log of integral. I maybe on an endless road of solving this question, but I wanted to know if such solution is possible. Here is my approach:

$$ I = \int e^{-x^2}dx $$
$$ I' = e^{-x^2} $$
Now taking $\ln$ on both the sides,
$$\ln I' = -x^2$$
Now, differentiating both sides,
$$ \frac{I''}{I'} = -2x $$
$$ I'' + 2xI' = 0 $$
With the initial conditions $I'(0) = 1$ and $I'(\infty) = 0$. 
I tried solving the above equation, but didn't succeed. Here are my approaches

- Case 1:
  Seeking solution in the form of $I(x) = x^\lambda$
  $$ I' = \lambda x^{\lambda -1}  $$
  $$ I'' = \lambda (\lambda -1 )x^{\lambda - 2} $$
  Putting the above in the differential equation
  $$ \lambda(\lambda - 1)x^{\lambda - 2} + 2x \lambda x^{\lambda - 1} = 0 $$
  $$ x^\lambda[ \lambda (\lambda - 1)x^2 + 2\lambda] = 0 $$
  Got $x^2$ term, so can't proceed further.
- Case 2
  Seeking solution in the form $I = e^{\lambda x}$
  $$ e^{\lambda x}[\lambda^2 + 2x \lambda] = 0 $$
  Got $x$ term, so can't proceed further.
- Case 3
  Using parameter $b$ here,
  $$ \int_0^bI'' dx = - \int_0^b 2xI' dx $$
  $$I'(b) - I'(0) = -2{[xI(x)]_0^b + 2 \int_0^b I(x) dx}$$
  Struck again.

Comment: This approach doesn't work at all, since $I$ is constant. Taking its derivative will give $0$, not $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: You should define $I(x)=\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt$ instead

Comment: This differential equation's solution cannot be expressed with only elementary functions. We actually call the function you'd use to solve it erf.

Comment: Yes, solution in elementary functions seems impossible. So, is there any other approach to solve the differential equation of such type?

Comment: What do you understand by "solving this question"? The solution **is** $\int e^{-x^2}dx$ and you **can't** express it in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: That's a valid point.

Comment: I think I should have inserted some parameters $b$ first  and then try to solve the new differential eqn of $F(b)$ which have $I$ as its coefficient (hence acting as a constant). Then the whole trick would be to use the parametrization method. Thanks for the help.